# My Angular project typescript config has a problem causing expect matchers to not work

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, cypress, karma-jasmine

My Angular project typescript config has a problem causing expect matchers to not work.   If I delete the cypress folder from my Angular project, the expect matchers work fine (including the intellisense).   So,  the existence of cypress in my project seems to cause this.

I have a pretty typical configuration I think.  I use `cypress-schematic` to define my cypress integration with my Angular 14 project.

The failures show up in my karma/jasmine *.spec.ts files.    Here is a screenshot of what I see:

[image]

Here is my `tsconfig.json` :

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": false,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": false,
    "strictTemplates": false
  }
}
```

Here is my `tsconfig.spec.json` :

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc/spec",
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "jasmine-expect",
      "cypress-commands",
      "cypress"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Here is my Cypress `cypress/tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "include": ["**/*.ts"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": false,
    "types": ["cypress"]
  },
  "types": [
    "jasmine",
    "cypress"
  ]
}
```

And finally, here is my `karma.config` :

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    files: [
      'node_modules/jasmine-expect/dist/jasmine-matchers.js'
    ],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma'),
      require('karma-jasmine-matchers'),
      require('jasmine-expect')
    ],
    ....
```

Answer (score 3):

I would think you want to exclude the cypress types from `tsconfig.spec.json` since that seems to be for karma tests

```js
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc/spec",
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "jasmine-expect",
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

And `cypress/tsconfig.json`

```js
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "include": ["**/*.ts"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": false,
    "types": ["cypress"]
  },
  "types": [
    "cypress"
  ]
}
```

If you're also running Cypress component tests and they live under `src/**/*.spec.ts`, that probably won't work.

Comment: Yes, Cypress uses chai and karma uses jasmine which have conflicting definitions of `expect()` and the other assertion methods. Separate tsconfigs for the win.

Comment: Yes, it does seem like the intellisense is showing e Chai-expect  in my .spec.ts Karma tests rather than the  jasmine-expect I need.     When you say "separate tsconfigs", i think you mean to not extend the parent tsconfig right?   Somehow, my unit test are picking up the Chai matchers library from the cypress subfolder.

Comment: Extends will be ok, there are no types in the base tsconfig